# CRUD generator for Struts 2 application

Tags: model-view-controller, struts2, crud

I have an already existing application built on Java 5 & Struts2 MVC framework having Oracle 11g DB.

Application has large number of tables which are often updated using insert queries or update statements 
and I am looking to develop a CRUD application and avoid any manual script execution.

Number of tables are very large with dependency over each other, so I was looking for a java framework which can directly generate the code based on existing table structure, with the flexibility to allow upload excel with data and provide a bulk update features.

Tried with Spring Roo but want to know if there are more framework which can be used with existing Struts 2 MVC.

Comment: A lot of frameworks are in the world, may be some fit your requirement, but your question doesn't fit SO rules.

Comment: Side note: J2EE is only Java 1.4, from 1.5 it is JAVA EE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CRUD application with Struts2 then you should look into [Struts 2 CRUD Tutorial](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-crud-example-1.html) .

The application example from Struts [Struts 2 CRUD Example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/CRUD+Demo+I)

> This example was created to be as simple as possible and as such, it does not use all of the advanced (integration) features such as Spring IoC, Hibernate Open-session-in-view, OS Sitemesh, annotations, etc .

You can also look at other [Examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Tutorials) at [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/struts-examples).

About java code generation you can use [Jboss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/features/hibernate.html).

> Hibernate Tools provides easy generation, testing and prototyping of your Hibernate or JPA mapped projects. Use it to Run queries, browse mappings and generate code for your data projects.

Consider *Reverse Engineering* section if you work on generating Java code.

### [image]

Put [*Hibernate Tools Reference Guide*](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html) to the desktop to read and help with any aspects of code-generation with Hibernate.

**References:**

- [Struts2 Builder Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/struts2builder/)
- [Easy CRUD with Struts 2 video](http://static.appfuse.org/movies/2.0/struts2-crud.mov)

Comment: this is a good aproach, but don't answers the question, maybe there are not a CRUD generators for Struts (only mixs of Pojo+JPA+<Some_template_engine>)

Comment: Look at [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/struts2builder/) may be it's what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is :

> Given an existing database, avoid coding manually the queries and the Java classes, and let instead ***{SMART_SOFTWARE}*** generates them for you.

Struts2 is a front-end MVC framework, it doesn't know anything *specific* about CRUD; while using Struts2, you are free to choose any persistence technology you like (JDBC, Hibernate, JPA, etc...).

Since the question involves Java EE, **the standard is JPA**.

If you're ok with using the Java Persistence API, then you're lucky! The software you're looking for is

## [Eclipse JPA Tools](http://shengwangi.blogspot.it/2014/12/how-to-create-java-classes-from-tables.html)

[image]

It's able to map the DB and create the Java classes (JPA Entities) by reverse-engineering the tables.

Note: there are equivalent tools for NetBeans and other IDE, if you're into them.

Comment: this is a good aproach, but don't answers the question, maybe there are not a CRUD generators for Struts (only mixs of Pojo+JPA+<Some_template_engine>)

Comment: I understand what you mean, and what you are hoping to find, but there isn't anything like that because... (and here it actually answers the question, stating that) Struts2 `doesn't know anything specific about CRUD`. Use JPA, and one of the above tools, or use JDBC, but forget automation (and dozens of other useful things). P.S: please, consider upvoting the answers you've found useful, and remember that the bounty points won't be reassigned to you, they'll be given to someone of your choice, or half lost and half given to the highest (voted) answer, or completely lost. Just saying...