# Eclipse Struts 2 Hibernate JPA configuration

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, configuration, struts2

I'm using Eclipse to build a web app, in which I want to use the framework Struts 2 and Hibernate. I'm not using Maven this time, only because I want to know how to make it work if I do not use Maven.

Version:

- Struts 2.5
- Hibernate 5.2.14

Now, the work set is:

[image]

META-INF and WEB-INF is:

[image]

As the image shown, `persistence.xml` is in META-INF and a `web.xml` file is in WEB-INF.

**`web.xml` (all part in web-app tag):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>LearningStruts</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**`struts.xml` (after DOCTYPE):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.locale" value="zh_CN"></constant>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="mess" />
    <constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
</struts>
```

Because I use annotation, all the configs are short.

**`persistence.xml` (all part in persistence) is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="CRM">
        <description>
            Persistence unit for Hibernate User Guide
        </description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In a class, I use annotation to inject `EntityManagerFactory`:

```
public class UserDao {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "CRM")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public void insert() {
        System.out.println(emf);
    }
}
```

but the output is `null`.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to create `EntityManager`:

```
EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CRM").createEntityManager();
```

The annotation might not used by the bean. You can learn more how to integrate frameworks example from [Getting Started](http://struts.apache.org/getting-started/).

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35887873/573032) answer for examples integration with  Spring.

Answer (score -1):

The class needs to be managed in order to be able to inject in it, either be `@Statelss` , `@Stateful` or a `Servlet` ... or Spring managed , something like that

Comment: Which jar is the annotation @stateful in? I'm using Hibernate 5.2.14. I have add all the required package, but no this annotation.

Comment: Additionally, if i use`EntityManagerFactory emf = Provider.createEntityManagerFactory ("CRM")` instead of the annotation way, it throws a **PersistenceException** with reason: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named CRM.