# EclipseLink JPA error: "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named (...)"

Tags: mysql, jpa, struts2, eclipselink

I'm using Struts 2 2.5.20 with EclipseLink JPA 2.7.4 in a Eclipse Java EE project. I believe there is some kind of problem with my `persistence.xml` file, since when I try to create a new `EntityManagerFactory` I get this error:

> WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No > Persistence provider for EntityManager named c_manager
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at contactManager.main.JPAImpl.main(JPAImpl.java:26)

Although I've found dozens of questions here in SO with this particular error, none of the solutions provided worked for me.

**JPAImpl.java**

```
public class JPAImpl
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("c_manager");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager(); //line 26
(...)
```

**Persistence.xml**

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="c_manager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>contactManager.model.jpa.entity.Contact</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contact_manager?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Project structure**

[image]

**Classpath**

[image]

Comment: I can't help much other then to suggest what you already suspect - the EclipseLink classes aren't found on the class path. Why depends on how you are running your main class - show the class path used to start the vm. Otherwise, enable logging within the persistence unit (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging) to see if it is getting that far and might be something else involved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49226232/573032