# Possible issues for not working Struts 2 application properly

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am new to Struts 2. Its initial release was in 2006. So when I followed a few login examples using struts 2, they did not work for many reasons. Since I was new to Struts 2, it was more difficult to find reasons for those issues. So I'm going to share some of the reasons why the Struts 2 application may not work properly. If I mention some wrongs, please be kind enough to correct them and if you know the reasons other than that, it's better to add them as answers.
Thank you.

Comment: You can start learning from the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49226232/573032).

Comment: Yes. I already know that. But I wanted to help others who are new to struts 2 like me. I found these solutions from different stackoverflow questions. Those are the reasons I found for my problem. If you know anything other than that, you can edit my answer, or add another answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, this is a Q&A site... But, Stackoverflow has given us the opportunity to answer our own questions. It's not something wrong. If answering own question is something that is not supposed to do, why Stackoverflow has given that option here? Hope you understand. Thanks.

Comment: @SennenRandika There's no question. Thr "answer" is links to existing documentation. The dependency advice is misleading. It ignores the best practice of using dependency  mgmt except for a brief mention at the end.

Comment: @DaveNewton In that case, may be you can edit the answer or post your own new answer. Isn't it? :)

Comment: @SennenRandika There's no question to post an answer to. If the questy was "what are the possible reasons an S2 application won't work", which is roughly what this boils down to, that would also be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. When add dependencies**

Don't add all the dependencies. Remember to add essential dependencies only.

[image]

Follow this link to download dependencies http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi

> **2. Check the struts 2 version in struts.xml file.**

I used struts 2.5.26. So I changed the version as 2.5 .
IF you use struts 2.3.37, you should change it to 2.3

```
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
 
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
```

> **3. Change filter package of web.xml file according to the version of struts 2**

**Changed filter package in Struts >= 2.5**

```
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter   </filter-class>
```

**Changed Filter Structure in Struts >= 2.1.3**

```
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
```

For more details https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/web-xml.html

I created my struts 2 application as a dynamic web project. As well as we can create struts 2 project as a maven project also.